# How to Bind the Property of an Instance?

Tags: sapui5

I created an array of objects:

```
buildPayerModel: function() {
    return [
        new SalesPayer("000", "2333", "033.433", "CHF"),
        new SalesPayer("000", "2333", "033.433", "CHF"),
        new SalesPayer("000", "2333", "033.433", "CHF")
    ];
}
```

and as a model:

```
this.getView().setModel(this.buildPayerModel(), "Sales")
```

Now I want to show the data in Table as the following:

```
<Table id="SalesView" inset="false" items="{ path: '/Sales' }">
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title text="Statistics" level="H2"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
        <Column width="12em">
            <Text text="Payer"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
            <Text text="Name"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="End">
            <Text text="Net Value"/>
        </Column>
        <Column hAlign="End">
            <Text text="Currency"/>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Sales.id}"/>
                <Text text="{Sales.name}"/>
                <Text text="{Sales.name}"/>
                <Text text="{Sales.name}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

How to access the property of the instance?

Comment: I think you're missing some basics of how data binding works in UI5. I'd recommend to follow at least the [walkthrough](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788558/5846045) might help for other learning resources.

Comment: I did. It shows only, how to bind it with a JSON object but not how can I access a class property. I tried also `{Sales>name}` but it does not work.

Comment: I followed https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/bf71375454654b44af01379a3c3a6273.html but could not help me.

Comment: You can use such instances in JSONModel as well. You weren't just using any model for data binding and the binding syntaxes were wrong too. Take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48299001/5846045) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `buildPayerModel()` is not building a model.
2. The API [`setModel`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/setModel) awaits a "subclass" of [sap.ui.model.Model](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model/methods/Summary) (not an array), and a corresponding **model name** (`"Sales"` in your case).
3. A *short* binding syntax looks as follows: `"{modelName>/propertyName}"`.

   - The binding is defined inside the curly brackets: `{` ... `}`
   - The `>` is needed when there is a model name.
   - The `/` at the beginning (right after possible `>`) indicates *absolute binding syntax*
   - Without <s>`/`</s> at the beginning --> `"{modelName>childPropertyName}"` indicates *relative binding syntax*. It is relative because such binding cannot be resolved without given context.

Given [JSONModel](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel) for the "Sales", and a *SalesPayer* instance contains direct properties such as `name` and `id`, here is a fix for you:

```
buildPayerModel: function() {
    return new /*sap.ui.model.json.*/JSONModel([
        new SalesPayer("000", "2333", "033.433", "CHF"),
        new SalesPayer("000", "2333", "033.433", "CHF"),
        new SalesPayer("000", "2333", "033.433", "CHF")
    ]);
},
```

Somewhere in the same controller:

```
this.getView().setModel(this.buildPayerModel(), "Sales")
```

XMLView:

```
<Table id="SalesView" inset="false" items="{Sales>/}">
    <headerToolbar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title text="Statistics" level="H2"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </headerToolbar>
    <columns>
        <Column width="12em">
            <Text text="Payer"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
            <Text text="Name"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="End">
            <Text text="Net Value"/>
        </Column>
        <Column hAlign="End">
            <Text text="Currency"/>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier title="{Sales>id}"/>
                <Text text="{Sales>name}"/>
                <Text text="{Sales>name}"/>
                <Text text="{Sales>name}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Comment: `It is relative because such binding cannot be resolved without given context` could you please provide an example?

Comment: @zero_coding Let's take the example `{Sales>name}`. The binding syntax is relative (no `/` at the beginning) and won't be able to resolve any value on the `text` property initially. The question is: "`name` of what?" There is no context. The context will be given once UI5 iterates through the array given by the aggregation binding (`items="{Sales>/}"`). Once the context is available for each item, the path can be resolved and the value can be "fetched" from the model. Resolved paths would look like `{Sales>/0/name}`, `{Sales>/1/name}`, etc..

Comment: @zero_coding Again, everything is explained in the [documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218). I understand that it's quite cumbersome to read that much, but don't just rely on random dudes like me who would explain important concepts vaguely and even incorrectly in some cases. You might become more confused.

Answer (score 1):

setModel() gets a model as first parameter, not a plain JSON Object or Array. Furthermore, the second parameter is the model name, if you name it as "Sales", you must use "Sales>" in your bindings. Then, remember: 
1. Use the "/" at the begining when building a path from the root of the model.
2. Avoid the "/" at the begining if you are binding a path relative to another context (Let's say the context of each row of the table)

Try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
   src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize_plus'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
     <Table id="SalesView" inset="false" items="{ path: 'Sales>/players' }">
          <headerToolbar>
              <Toolbar>
                  <Title text="Statistics" level="H2"/>
              </Toolbar>
          </headerToolbar>
          <columns>
              <Column width="12em">
                  <Text text="Payer"/>
              </Column>
              <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                  <Text text="Name"/>
              </Column>
              <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" hAlign="End">
                  <Text text="Net Value"/>
              </Column>
              <Column hAlign="End">
                  <Text text="Currency"/>
              </Column>
          </columns>
          <items>
              <ColumnListItem>
                  <cells>
                      <ObjectIdentifier title="{Sales>id}"/>
                      <Text text="{Sales>name}"/>
                      <Text text="{Sales>name}"/>
                      <Text text="{Sales>name}"/>
                  </cells>
              </ColumnListItem>
          </items>
      </Table>
    </mvc:View> 
    </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
    onInit: function(){
      
     this.getView().setModel(this.buildPayerModel(), "Sales")
    },
    
    buildPayerModel: function() {
          var oModelData = {
            "players": [
              {"id": 001, "name": "Michael Jordan"},
              {"id": 002, "name": "Kobe Bryant"},
              {"id": 003, "name": "LeBron James"}
            ]
          };
          var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oModelData)
          return oModel;
        }
   });
 
   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above
   
   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');
  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your oModelData is different then my. I am using object instance and your are using JSON format. It is difference not?